# Is it possible to add a direct command to Google Assistant API?

Tags: google-assistant-sdk, google-assist-api

I am working on an Arduino project and I was curious if it is possible to add a "direct command" to Google assistant on android.
I've searched a bit and all I could find is having the Assistant do things like "Hey Google, let's talk to Application Name" but I think that's a little annoying to use, I wanted to know is if it's possible to add like "Hey Google do this" and it would like open a specific website.
Is is possible or I'm out of luck?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [explicit invocation](https://developers.google.com/actions/discovery/explicit) to trigger a Google Assistant action.

The user can include an invocation phrase at the end of their invocation that will take them directly to the function they're requesting, like so:

[image: Explicit invocation on Google Assistant]

"Hey Google do this" would be an example of invocation that is currently only available to partners. Since Spotify has a relationship with Google, for example, users can say "Hey Google, play Despacito on Spotify." If you would like to create Actions using parnter solutions, you will need to [contact support](https://assistant.google.com/business/form/) to request access and become a partner.

As a third party developer, the closest you can get to mimicking the feature you're requesting is, `"Hey Google, talk to My App Name about visiting www.example.com"`, which could trigger an intent that would respond with a [browsing carousel](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/responses#browsing_carousel) of links to www.example.com and any other websites you would like to suggest.